# Javascript Array Map by Object Attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic rendering component, that renders sub-components as follows. I`m making the component inside another object now and i could not re-write the render part.

**Rendering**

```
{this.props.components.map((Component, i) => (
  <div className="formGroup" key={i}>
     <Component id={Component.componentName + "_id"} name={Component.componentName} ref={component => { this.componentRefs.push(component); console.log("Loaded component " + component.componentName); }} key={i} />
  </div>
))}
```

For now i have a brute array of components such as

```
this.props.components = [MyComponent1, MyComponent2];
```

However, i`m changing this in a way i have the component wrapped inside an object, such as

```
this.props.components = [{type: MyComponent1, name:"yolo"}, {type: MyComponent2, name:"yala"},];
```

so the component itself is inside this object `type`attribute.

I didnt managed to re-write the render part of this component to loop for this type attribute instead of the object itself.

Comment: I'm not sure you asked a question.

Comment: Please revise your post to clearly state your question - right now it reads as a list of items regarding your work not a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deconstruct the `type` property off the object on mapping:

```
{this.props.components.map(({ type: MyComponent }, i) => (
    <div className="formGroup" key={i}>
        <MyComponent id={Component.componentName + "_id"}
            name={Component.componentName}
            ref={component => {
                this.componentRefs.push(component);
                console.log("Loaded component " + component.componentName); 
            }}
            key={i} />
    </div>
))}
```